# how to remove the text "Administrator:" from the cmd window?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, administrator

Although a near identical question was asked, the answer won't work (for me at least) with my Vista system.

I am using an elevated prompt to run a batch file. Since the batch file takes awhile to run through, I want to update the "title" with progress updates.

Using the "title" command updates the text after the "Administrator:" but because of the "Administrator:" text, you cannot read it... example: "Admnistrator: Tes..." instead of "Testing 1-2-3"

How can I remove the "Administrator:" text completely (while still using an elevated prompt)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you completely dead set on using cmd.exe? If you wanted to use powershell to run the batch script, you can use `$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Status Here"` for full control of the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I stumbled upon is that the second command on the same line when using "&&" will replace the command window title without the "Administrator:" prefix.

For example, instead of the batch file line with your command:

```
long-running-command /flags
```

Try this:

```
true && long-running-command /flags
```

Not sure how to set a custom title, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your shell using `RUNAS` then "Administrator" doesn't appear in the title and using `TITLE` completely replaces the one that is displayed.

```
c:\> RUNAS /user:computer\adminuser cmd
```

Or you can create a shortcut using that line.

Comment: Just tried that on Vista, as user who is an Administrator, and it still had *Administrator:* in the title after `TITLE cmd`

Comment: @yhw42: Are you running it from an already elevated shell? Try it from a normal shell.

Comment: I am always administrator (no lecture please). I also have a complex password. Maybe it's impossible...

Answer (score 0):

This appears whenever you run elevated command prompt.

- As @DavidHoude said, you can use `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle`, surprisingly It could be also applied in Cmd. Like:

```
powershell -nop -c "& {$host.ui.rawui.windowtitle='YOUR TITLE'}"
```

- Or if you don't require elevation, then run a non-elevated command prompt and run `title <nul`.